# How to install jcopvision.draw on my Conda envrionment?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, yolo, face-landmark

Environment configuration:

[image: Environment configuration]

Error prompt:

[image: Error prompt]

And I cannot install jcopvision in this environment.

How can I get over this error?

```
(cow_detection) PS F:\project\Insignia\RampSure\15 Sept\Cow-Detection-using-OpenCV-main> conda install jcopvision
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

This is the error I am facing while trying to install jcopvision.draw.